# HMMs: Difference between the joint and conditional probabilities

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, hidden-markov-models

I am having trouble in giving meaning to the joint and conditional probabilities related to the observations and states of HMMs in the [Appendix A](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ejurafsky/slp3/A.pdf) of Speech and Language Processing by Jurafsky and Martin.
More specifically, a forward trellis is defined as follows in page 6 of the appendix:

> The forward algorithm trellis α$_{t}(j)$ represents the probability of being in state $j$ after seeing the first $t$ observations.

Formally,

> α$_t(j)=P(o_1, ..., o_t, q_t=j|$ λ$)$

On the other hand, on page 13, ξ$_t(i, j)$ is defined as:

> ... the probability of being in state $i$ at time $t$ and state $j$ at time $t+1$.

Also formally,

> ξ$_t(i, j)=P(q_t=i, q_{t+1}=j|$ $O,$ λ$)$

I understand why in the trellis' case, the observations might be taken as part of the joint probability. But why are we conditioning the states on the observations when computing ξ$_t(i, j)$?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question properly. The whole point of that section, as stated at the beginning of the section (bottom of p. $10$) and again on page $12$, is to learn the parameters from an observation sequence. It seems natural that that would involve probabilities conditioned on the observations. The $\xi_i$ are defined as probabilities "given the observation sequence". Could you elaborate why you nevertheless find it surprising that they are thus conditioned?

Comment: Well, I find that the colloquial definitions of both α() and (,) (referenced in the post) are pretty similar. So what I don't understand, is why in the first one, the probability is "given λ", the  being part of the joint probability, and in the second one, the probability is "given  and λ". From the wording of the definition of (,), I would have expected it to also be "given λ", including  in the joint probability. Thanks.